# Multiprocessing makes the code slower than expected - using Cython and using vanilla Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, cython

Got to give credit to NeuralNine video about Cython - [from here I got the code.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ic1oE6SEOBs&ab_channel=NeuralNine)

Here I have a `.pyx` that contains two functions that are doing the same thing, which is given an integer `amount` returns a list of all the prime numbers below that number.

`prime_finder_vanilla` - Pure python
`prime_finder_optimized` - Cython

```py
def prime_finder_vanilla(amount):
    primes = []
    found = 0
    number = 2
    while found < amount:
        for x in primes:
            if number % x == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(number)
            found += 1
        number += 1
    return primes


def prime_finder_optimized(int amount):
    cdef int number, x, found
    cdef int primes[100_000]

    amount = min(amount, 100_000)
    found = 0
    number = 2
    while found < amount:
        for x in primes[:found]:
            if number % x == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes[found] = number
            found += 1

        number += 1

    return_list = [p for p in primes[:found]] # <--- ?! why not just return primes[:found] lol
    return return_list
```

I've compiled the file with the command line:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup  (
    ext_modules=cythonize('testing_cython.pyx')
)
```

Now, I did run both functions, and it really seems that the Cython implementation is faster! but what I always like to do, is build a third part method that runs these functions for a given range, and calculates the average time it took to run these functions and get more accurate statistics of how optimized it really is.

So this is my "third party optimization analysis" file:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

import testing_cython


def check_performance(fn, tests_amount, tests_amount_start=1_000):
    times = []

    for amount in range(tests_amount_start, tests_amount_start + tests_amount + 1):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        fn(amount)
        times.append(time.perf_counter() - start)

    return sum(times) / len(times)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    starting_time = time.perf_counter()
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    res1 = pool.apply_async(check_performance, args=(testing_cython.prime_finder_vanilla, 300))
    # res1 = res1.get()
    res2 = pool.apply_async(check_performance, args=(testing_cython.prime_finder_optimized, 300))
    # res2 = res2.get()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(f"With multiprocessing: {time.perf_counter() - starting_time} seconds")
    # print(f"{res1=}\n{res2=}\n{res1/res2=}")

    print('-' * 30)

    starting_time = time.perf_counter()
    check_performance(testing_cython.prime_finder_vanilla, 300)
    print(f"After vanilla sequentially: {time.perf_counter() - starting_time}")
    check_performance(testing_cython.prime_finder_optimized, 300)
    print(f"Without multiprocessing: {time.perf_counter() - starting_time} seconds")
```

Basically what it does is it takes any function `fn`, the amount of tests we want to do `tests_amount`, and the starting point to check the primes `tests_amount_start`, so if we give it `tests_amount=5` and leave `tests_amount_start` as it is, it will return the average runtime of: `fn(1000), f(1001), f(1002), f(1003), f(1004), f(1005)`

Getting this result:

```
With multiprocessing: 5.528125900003943 seconds
------------------------------
After vanilla sequentially: 4.921810699997877
Without multiprocessing: 5.678506500000367 seconds
```

What I don't get is that simple math:
If sequentially the average running time of the vanilla is `4.9218` and the whole process sequentially took `5.678`, this means that on average, the optimized version should take `5.678 - 4.921 = 0.757`.

So, why is it with multiprocessing it takes `5.528` and not `4.921` - which is the running time of the heavy vanilla code? because the optimized version was running in parallel to the vanilla, it should be "included" in the total runtime... no?

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you're running more tests with the pool - you set `tests_amount` to 1000 instead of 300. The pool actually seems to be finishing far too quickly.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry! I've updated only the sequential to 300 here, the code uses 300 for all measures. I will update, thank you. The results stay the same though!